# Regular Expression for java script

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i want regular expression for this tag

```
img src="http://cache01.g2gtoolkit.com/sites/all/themes/base_hospital_theme/css/images/loading-gif-animation.gif" width="20px" height="20px"
```

can anyone help me ?

I have tried many things

```
imgsrc="http://[^/]+/sites/all/themes/base_hospital_theme/css/images/(.*?)width=.*?
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe you need such a thing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: the regex looks ok to me, altough if you are using the /.*/ style of declaring regexes, you should escape all the /

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
 "http://[^/]+/sites/all/themes/base_hospital_theme/css/images/([^"]*)"[\S\s]*?width

 stringified:

 "\"http://[^/]+/sites/all/themes/base_hospital_theme/css/images/([^\"]*)\"[\\S\\s]*?width"
```